# Twitter bootstrap: how to add side margins?

Tags: layout, twitter, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with centered Twitter Bootstrap container .

This container has a header that spans the entire width (span12) and below the header is a gallery of pictures, which is a bunch of rows with 4 cells (containing pictures) in each row.

I would like to add side margins to each row so that the first and last picture are not completely snug with container borders and pictures are spaced equally. I don't want to use offset1 for the margin because it is way too big.

Here is a link to the current mockup: http://i46.tinypic.com/21e2h4o.jpg

Comment: Can you post a demo in jsfiddle.net with your markup or a mockup picture? I'm finding it hard trying to visualize what it is that ou want.

Comment: I included a link to mockup in my original post. Thanks

Comment: have you tried the fluid class? container-fluid row-fluid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the nth-child css property

`nth-child(4n+1)` for the left margin

`nth-child(4n+4)` for the right margin

http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Or

add a `<div>` in your `.span12` with `style="padding:0 19px"`

and add inside a `<div class="row-fluid">`

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span12">
    <div style="padding:0 19px">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">3</div>
        <div class="span3">3</div>
        <div class="span3">3</div>
        <div class="span3">3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I know how to use jQuery and CSS3 selectors to set the margin. But this approach interferes with the natural way Twitter Bootstrap lays out cells in row and I will have to adjust the margins according to the size of media. So, I was looking for a way to do this with Twitter Bootstrap configurations.

Comment: It is not a good idea to use pixels to set padding or margins.

Comment: @JGEstiot FYI 2012 = Bootstrap 2

Answer (score 0):

span12 is 940px wide. That should be the width of your workspace or whatever. 960px seems to be a pretty common practice among grid systems.

Here's my solution...

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: #CCC;
        }

        #SiteBody 
        {
            width: 960px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="SiteBody">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                    <h1>
                        My Page</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```